# Merge both audio with delay use ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I have a project that wants to use ffmpeg to merge 2 audio 1.mp3 and 2.mp3 like this:
(length of audio 1.mp3 is longer than length of audio 2.mp3)

```
|<---------------------------------- 1st mp3 file ---------------------------------------->|
|<-----12s------><-----------2nd mp3 file -------------><-------15s------>|

result:
|<------------------------output_audio.mp3------------------------------->|
```

Ths for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Use the [adelay](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#adelay) and [amix](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amix) filters:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp3 -i 2.mp3 -filter_complex "[1:a]adelay=12s:all=1[a1];[0:a][a1]amix=inputs=2[a]" -map "[a]" output.mp3
```

Comment: It doesn't work with the newest ffmpeg version https://github.com/mifi/editly/issues/155